# Como criar uma lista a partir dos dados salvos no local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5, json

Estou com uma tarefa em que preciso criar um registro para usuários, salvar no local storage e depois em uma lista mostrar no site todos os usuários registrados. Eu consegui salvar os dados dos usuários, mas estou tendo problemas  na parte da listagem para mostrar na página os dados dos usuários registrados, não faço ideia de como fazer essa parte.

Ta aí o que fiz até agora. O JS e o html.

```
function salvarConteudoStorage() {
```

var arraycadastro=[]
if(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("dados")) != null){
    arraycadastro.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("dados")));
}

if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {

```
var nome = document.getElementById("fnome").value;
var email = document.getElementById("femail").value;
var imagem = document.getElementById("imagem").value;
var repositorio = document.getElementById("repositorio").value;


var info = {nome, email, imagem, repositorio};
console.log(info);
arraycadastro.push(info);
var infoJson = JSON.stringify(arraycadastro);
localStorage.setItem("dados", infoJson);
```

}
  else {
    window.alert("API Web Storage não encontrada");
  }
}

```
<body>
    <div>

      <form action="#">
        <div >
          <input type="text" id="fnome"/>
          <label for="fnome">Nome</label>
        </div>
        <div >
          <input  type="text" id="femail"/>
          <label  for="femail">E-mail</label>
        </div>
        <div >
          <input  type="text" id="imagem"/>
          <label  for="imagem">URL da imagem</label>
        </div>
        <div >
          <input  type="text" id="repositorio"/>
          <label  for="repositorio">Github</label>
        </div>                
      </form>  

      <button  onclick="salvarConteudoStorage()">
        Salvar
      </button>

    </div>
    <script
          src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
          integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
<script src="armazenar.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OBS: Antes de tudo teste na sua máquina. no site pode não funcionar por questões de segurança por estar salvando localmente.
Modifiquei a funçao salvar. e criei outra só para buscar que você pode chamar logo quando carregar a página.
Espero ter ajudado.

```js
const tBody = document.getElementById('corpoTabela');

function salvarConteudoStorage() {
  let arraycadastro = [];

  if (localStorage.getItem('dados') != null) {
    arraycadastro = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('dados'));
  } else {
    arraycadastro;
  }

  var nome = document.getElementById("fnome").value;
  var email = document.getElementById("femail").value;
  var imagem = document.getElementById("imagem").value;
  var repositorio = document.getElementById("repositorio").value;


  var info = {
    nome,
    email,
    imagem,
    repositorio
  };

  arraycadastro.push(info);
  var infoJson = JSON.stringify(arraycadastro);
  localStorage.setItem("dados", infoJson);

  buscarConteudo();
}


function buscarConteudo() {
  const arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('dados'));

  if (arr != null) {
    let tr = '';
    arr.map(conteudo => {
      tr += `
   <tr>
     <td>${conteudo.nome}</td>
     <td>${conteudo.email}</td>
     <td>${conteudo.imagem}</td>
     <td>${conteudo.repositorio}</td>
    </tr>`


    })
    tBody.innerHTML = tr;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>

  <form>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="fnome" />
      <label for="fnome">Nome</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="femail" />
      <label for="femail">E-mail</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="imagem" />
      <label for="imagem">URL da imagem</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="repositorio" />
      <label for="repositorio">Github</label>
    </div>
  </form>

  <button onclick="salvarConteudoStorage()">
   Salvar
  </button>

</div>

<div>
  <table>
    <th>nome</th>
    <th>E-mail</th>
    <th>url</th>
    <th>Github</th>
    <tbody id="corpoTabela">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Ajudou bastante cara, obrigado. Mas agora tenho outro dúvida: Na parte da imagem, quando usuário colocasse uma url de uma imagem na caixa de texto, essa imagem deveria carregar na hora de exibir os dados, e eu vi que você usou Jquery e eu não manjo muito dele, você tem alguma ideia de como fazer isso?

Comment: Na verdade não usei jquery não, rs. Este é um padrão novo do ES6 javasCript, template string. No lugar de adicionar o td <td>${conteudo.imagem}</td>, você pode colocar um <img src={${conteudo.imagem}}> lembrando que o conteúdo imagem deve ser uma URL para que busque o usúario. Se ajudou da um UP na resposta pra me dar uma força, kkk. E coloca a questão como resolvida, isso me ajuda muito a continuar resolvendo questões aqui

Comment: Votei, mas como sou novo meu voto não é 'contabilizado'. Então mano, tentei fazer isso que você falou com a imagem e está dando esse erro "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND". Essa maldita imagem é a única coisa que  falta. Obg pela ajuda novamente =D.